# add/remove required attribute dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, required

I want to add/remove the required attribute of an input element. But somehow it doesn't work.

If offender Plate# text field is empty, Describe vehicle text field should be required.

Offender Plate #: `<input type="text" id="plate_num_id" name="plate_num" onblur="checkForRequired()"><br>`

Describe Vehicle: `<textarea id="vehicle_desc_id" name="vehicle_desc"></textarea><br>`

Then here is my function.

```
function checkForRequired() {

    var plateLength = document.getElementById("plate_num_id").value.length;

    if (plateLength < 1) {

        $("#vehicle_desc_id").add('required');
    } else {

        $("#vehicle_desc_id").removeAttr('required');
    }
}
```

I have also tried other methods:

```
document.getElementById("vehicle_desc_id").removeAttribute("requried");

document.getElementById("vehicle_desc_id ").required = true/false;

document.getElementById("vehicle_desc_id ").setAttribute("required ", "");
```

None seems to be working...

Comment: `$("#vehicle_desc_id").prop('required', true)`

Comment: never seen  onblur/onfocusout as an attribute, Does that work as it's supposed to ? try seperating them.`onfocusout="checkForRequired()"onblur="checkForRequired()"` what does the console say? any errors

Comment: remove the spaces after the opening angle brackets....< input should be <input and < br should be<br

Comment: It's supposed to be seperated. I just meant that I have tried using the two. So yes, I've tried both, onfocusout="checkForRequired()"onblur="checkForRequired()". And that's not what seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 6):

works when you sort the html out and remove space after brackets, edited again to remove after details if corrected

```js
function checkForRequired() {

    var plateLength = document.getElementById("plate_num_id").value.length;
var vehicle = document.getElementById("vehicle")
    if (plateLength < 1) {

        vehicle.setAttribute('required','required');
    } else {
 
      vehicle.removeAttribute('required');
    }
}
```

```css
input:required{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="plate_num_id" name="plate_num" onblur/onfocusout="checkForRequired()"><br/><br>
<input type="text" id="vehicle" />
```