# Parsley validating checkbox that has no required attribute, but fails to validate select that has

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, jquery-select2, parsley.js

In the below code I have an form with 2 select fields that when checkbox either checked or unchecked shows up depending on the state ..

in the jQuery I set the attribute for required depending on the select field that is "active". My checkbox does not have required attribute set, actually I have actively tried to exclude it in the script as documentet for Parsley version >2.1, and setting `$("#SystemMessageChk").attr('required', false)` in both toggle modes, but no matter what I do it still validates the checkbox and not the active select when I check the box, and submit the form.

Anyone with an idea for a fix?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(function() {
    $("#SystemMessageChk").click(function() {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("#MessageSystemDIV").show();
        $("#MessageSpecificUserDIV").hide();
        $("#MessageSystemType").attr('required', true);
        $("#MessageReceipients1").attr('required', false)
        $("#SystemMessageChk").attr('required', false)
      } else {
        $("#MessageSystemDIV").hide();
        $("#MessageSpecificUserDIV").show();
        $("#MessageSystemType").attr('required', false)
        $("#MessageReceipients1").attr('required', true);
        $("#SystemMessageChk").attr('required', false)
      }
    });
  });

  $('#MessageSystemType').selectpicker();
  $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2({
    placeholder: 'Vælg modtager(e)...'
  });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/bootstrap4-toggle@3.6.1/css/bootstrap4-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/bootstrap4-toggle@3.6.1/js/bootstrap4-toggle.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parsley.js/2.9.2/parsley.min.js"></script>

<form id="MessageCenterForm" name="MessageCenterForm" action="send_message_messagecenter.asp" data-parsley-validate="" data-parsley-excluded="input[type=button], input[type=submit], input[type=reset], input[type=hidden], input[type=checkbox], [disabled], :hidden"
  class="demo-form" type="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="MessageReceipients" class="col-form-label">Receiver(s):</label>

    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label-sm" for="SystemMessageChk">
                System message
            </label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="SystemMessageChk" name="SystemMessageChk" value="yes" data-parsley-excluded="true">
    </div>


    <div id="MessageSpecificUserDIV">

      <select class="form-control js-example-basic-multiple" id="MessageReceipients1" name="MessageReceipients1" placeholder="Vælg modtagere" multiple style="width: 100%" data-parsley-errors-container="#MessageReceipients-errors" required>
        <option value=""></option>
        <optgroup label="1 - Some Group">
          <option value="1">Some Name</option>
        </optgroup>
      </select>

    </div>

    <div id="MessageReceipients-errors"></div>

    <div id="MessageSystemDIV" style="display: none;">
      <select id="MessageSystemType" id="MessageSystemType" class="form-control form-control-sm" data-show-content="true">
        <option value="">Choose type..</option>
        <option value="" data-content="&nbsp;<i class='fas fa-exclamation text-info'></i>&nbsp; Information"></option>
        <option value="" data-content="<i class='fas fa-check text-success'></i> Solved"></option>
        <option value="" data-content="<i class='fas fa-exclamation-triangle text-warning'></i> Warning"></option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Message:</label>
      <textarea class="maxLength form-control" id="message-text" maxLength="250" required></textarea>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" form="MessageCenterForm" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [add/remove required attribute dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27731561/add-remove-required-attribute-dynamically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to remove `$("#SystemMessageChk").attr('required', false)` and add `$("#MessageReceipients-errors").html("");` to first toggle, in other words it was a matter of clearing the error text.

**Working code is :**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $(function () {
            $("#SystemMessageChk").click(function () {
                if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                    $("#MessageSystemDIV").show();
                    $("#MessageSpecificUserDIV").hide();
                    $("#MessageSystemType").attr('required',true);
                    $("#MessageReceipients1").attr('required',false);
                    $("#MessageReceipients-errors").html("");                    
                } else {
                    $("#MessageSystemDIV").hide();
                    $("#MessageSpecificUserDIV").show();
                    $("#MessageSystemType").attr('required',false);
                    $("#MessageReceipients1").attr('required',true);              
                }
            });
        });

    $('#MessageSystemType').selectpicker();
    $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2({
        placeholder: 'Vælg modtager(e)...'
    });

});
```